# Azure load balancer

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8, azure-networking

I have an on prem web server we want to make high availability. We was looking at iis arr.

if we setup another iis web server at a different site and setup dfs to replicate content, i would like to know if we can setup an azure load balancer to talk to manage both servers just in case a site goes down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is Azure Traffic Manager. It is designed to do just what you are trying to do. Azure load balancer is not a good fit to load balance across on-prem\cloud.

If you will use Traffic Manager you can manage those sites completely independently.

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview